# How do I set MySQL CLI to use pager output by default?

Tags: mysql, configuration

I found this wonderful output format for the MySQL CLI [here](https://www.alexkras.com/my-sql-pretty-print-in-command-line/). The command is `mysql> pager less -SFX`. I would like this to be my default and not have to enter the command every time I start the MySQL CLI. How can I go about setting this as a default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pager can be set from the `mysql` client commandline with the [`--pager=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_pager) option.

So one option is setting up an alias in your shell such that your custom pager is always set  in your ~/.bashrc something similar to :

```
alias mysql='mysql --pager="/usr/bin/less -SFX"'
```

Alternatively any [`--option=` commandline option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html) can be set as `option=` in the relevant section of your personal `~/.my.cnf` file. For instance:

```
[mysql]
pager="/usr/bin/less -SFX"
```